# For odd integers $a,b,c$ line $ax+by+c=0$ cannot intersect parabola $y=x^2$ in a rational point

Tags: number-theory, quadratics

For odd integers $a,b,c$ line $ax+by+c=0$ cannot intersect parabola $y=x^2$ in a rational point(where both abscissa and ordinate are rational numbers.)

---

We need to solve the equation of the line $ax+by+c=0$ with the parabola $y=x^2$.
Put $y=x^2$ in the equation $ax+by+c=0$,we get $bx^2+ax+c=0$,
Now we need to check whether the discriminant of the quadratic equation is a perfect square or not.
Discriminant $=a^2-4bc$
As $a,b,c$ are odd integers,let $a=2k_1+1,b=2k_2+1,c=2k_3+1$
Discriminant $=a^2-4bc=(2k_1+1)^2-4(2k_2+1)(2k_3+1)$
$=4k_1^2+4k_1-16k_2k_3-8k_2-8k_3-3$
But I do not know whether $4k_1^2+4k_1-16k_2k_3-8k_2-8k_3-3$ is a perfect square or not

Comment: For there to be rational roots then there has to exist two factors of $bc$ which adds to give $a$, e.g. $14x^2 +31x + 15 = 14x^2 + 21x + 10x + 15 = 7x(2x + 3) + 5(2x + 3) = (7x + 5)(2x + 3)$.  But if $b$ and $c$ are both odd, then $bc$ is also odd, which means that any two factors much be odd--but two odds add to give an even number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:

Assume that $bx^2 + ax + c = 0$ has rational roots and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are odd.  This means that there exists four integers, $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$, and $k_4$ such that:

\begin{align}
bx^2 + ax + c =&\ (k_1x + k_2)(k_3x + k_4)\\
=&\ k_1k_3x^2 + (k_1k_4 + k_2k_3)x + k_2k_4
\end{align}

Because $b$ and $c$ *must* be odd, we can assume that $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$, and $k_4$ must *all* be odd (since $k_1k_3 = b$ must be odd and $k_2k_4 = c$ must be odd).  If all of those are odd, then $k_1k_4$ is odd and $k_2k_3$ is odd and therefore $k_1k_4 + k_2k_3 = a$ must be even since an odd plus an odd results in an even number.

This is a contradiction to the assumption that $a$ is odd, and thus it *cannot* be the case that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are odd *and* you have a rational intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $a,b,c$ are odd, $bx^2+ax+c=0$ and $x$ is rational.  Let $x=p/q$ where $p,q$ are integers with no common factor.  Then
$$bp^2+apq+cq^2=0\ .$$
Reading the equation modulo $2$, we have $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv 1$; also $p^2\equiv p$ and $q^2\equiv q$; hence
$$p+pq+q\equiv0\ .$$
Therefore
$$(p+1)(q+1)\equiv1\ ;$$
this implies
$$p+1\equiv q+1\equiv1$$
and so
$$p\equiv q\equiv0\ .$$
That is, $p$ and $q$ are both even, which is a contradiction since we assumed they have no common factor.